# What is this micro Mega Bloks element?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

I've got this Mega Bloks brick that's a 2x4 and it's smaller than the standard brick, it's 3/4"x3/8" and half the height as the standard brick. It was attached to a vehicle frame that also had two transparent red flat 1x1 that are 1/2cm attached to the frame where taillights would be. Does anybody know what set is it from?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I added photos of the frame. FYI there is a screw on the bottom.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to identify a megabloks set based on a single common part. This is like asking what set a black 2x4 lego brick is from.

Comment: I didn't think there was that many sets of there that has those size bricks. I thought maybe it was to a car hauler and the cars were built with the smaller bricks, or something similar like that. How Hot Wheels put out a car hauler with mini cars, which some were color changers.

Comment: Smaller 1 Nano, & bigger micro? Micro size of System Lego, & I guess Nano the size of smaller Lego called Modulex. So like 2/5" × 4/5" for 2 ×4.

Answer (score 0):

Guess could be 5902, instructions for sale on eBay, rally car. Could be all 4-wheel bases the same. Hopefully can add Modulex bricks to a base with wheels to make another car.[image]